# SQL query with OUTER RIGHT JOIN

Tags: sql

I have two tables, say table1 has 7 records and table2 has only 2 records. I want the matching records from the both the tables i.e., only 2 records from the 2nd table. I'm not sure of using joins here.

When I execute the query, it was displaying all the 7 records. Suggest me with your idea. I tried with RIGHT JOIN, but still 7 records were displaying.

TABLE1

```
id  deptid
3     3
2     3 
4     3
7     3
91    3 
31    3
55    3
```

TABLE2

```
id  deptid dname
1     3     A
2     3     B


SELECT t1.id, t2.dname FROM TABLE1 t1 JOIN TABLE t2 ON t2.deptid = t1.deptid
```

Comment: Please show the results you want.  It seems like you want an `inner join`, though.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - I want the second table results i.e., only 2 records.

Answer (score 0):

could be you need  a distinct clause

```
  SELECT distinct t1.id, t2.dname 
  FROM TABLE1 t1 
  JOIN TABLE t2 ON t2.deptid = t1.deptid
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tables do not have a full key joining them -- `deptid` is not enough.  You can generate another key using `row_number()`:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.dname
FROM (SELECT t1.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY deptid ORDER BY id) as seqnum
      FROM TABLE1 t1
     ) t1 JOIN
     (SELECT t2.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY deptid ORDER BY id) as seqnum
      FROM TABLE t2
     ) t2
     ON t2.deptid = t1.deptid AND t2.seqnum = t1.seqnum;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY deptid ORDER BY id) as seqnum FROM TABLE t1) t1
JO' at line 3

Comment: @sagasun . . . (1) This is standard SQL and your question has no database tag.  (2) MySQL 8+ supports window functions so there should be no syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Your Table1 contains All the deptid present in Table2, so using any of the join will give you all the records.

If what you are expecting is, The deptid in Table2 which exists in Table1 then you need to use inner query or CTE.

Select * from Table2 where deptid in (Select deptid from Table1);

Comment: If Select * from Table2 where deptid =...., it was displaying the table 1 records, but I need the second table records, i.e., 2 records

Comment: If the statement itself says Select something from Table2, it will never show records of Table1. May be you have not explained the question clearly.

Comment: Also mention of there is any relevance of 'id' column in the tables.